# Programmatically set cookies in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, cookies

I'll start by explaining the scenario:

I have a IE browser in the computer A. Inside the IE I have a plugin so I can access to the Document Object, so I can grab the cookie in a given time.

I want to transfer that cookie to a new browser in a different computer B.

In order to start the browser in the new computer B I use the InternetExplorer object, I can control the browser using the object instance, but I don't know how to "inject" the cookie of the first computer A to the newly created IE Browser.

I have tried two ways.

- First, I tried to write the cookie before starting the browser using WinInet API ***InternetSetCookie***.
- And Secondly, I tried to intercept the ***BeforeNavigate2*** Event and set the cookie in the header of the HTTP request.

But none of those have worked :(

Is It possible to set a cookie in a new Internet Explorer before navigate to a website and therefore be able to maintain the sesion the user had in his previous computer?

Thanks :)

**UPDATE**: I'm still having this issue and did some other investigations using wireshark.

In the case of BeforeNavigate2, the IExplore simply ignore the "Cookie:"  value in the header.

In the case of InternetSetCookie, it seems it's working properly. It create the same file the regular IExplore navigation creates, but when you go to that page, the IE ignores the file which contains the cookie.

The code i'm using to write the cookie is:

```
string cookie = "COOKIEVALUES";
InternetSetCookie("http://www.facebook.com/", "", cookie+";expires=Sat, 08-Jan-2014 00:00:00 GMT");
```

Answer (score 3):

InternetSetCookie() should be the proper way of doing it.  Have you verified you're setting  the correct values?  Are you using a canonicalized url?  Are you specifying an expiration date?  Getting the URL wrong (I'm not sure if things such as trailing /'s matter or not) will have obvious consequences, and if you don't set an expiration date the cookie is held in memory for the current process only.

Comment: I'm not totally sure about that. I need to check how the stored cookies work. But, I tried to copy the cookie file across computers and didn't work :-S

Comment: I'm not able to work with this method. To begin with, I'm not completely sure which ones are the cookies of a given site.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to use a tool like IEdebugBar - it will show you all sent and received headers in a clean way.

Second, have you verified that the cooky doesn't get send to the server? Since it seems you are trying to 'steal' a facebook session,I would assume that facebook will ignore a session-cookie coming from a browser with a different IP, UserAgent etc. Have you taken this into consideration?

Comment: I'm tracking the requests using wireshark, so I can see the real http header and cookie is not sent :(. If I send the same cookie using a script it actually works. The problem is that IE doesn't want to send the cookie I'm pointing it to send.

Comment: Is teh cooki-date escaped in the right way? Have you tried NULL instead of ""? (That's what I found in an example on msdn). And have oyu tried to remove the space from your expires date? (between "Sat," and "08-") -- 
InternetSetCookie("http://msdn.microsoft.com", NULL, "TestData = Test; expires = Sat,06-Jan-2007 00:00:00 GMT");

Comment: Yep, I've tried that. Indeed, If you dont put the expire date correctly, the InternetSetCookie method returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/d46f0797-5ddb-40c0-af71-2178fa019da8

Check this text

> After comparing the 2 environments where the code and works and where
>   it doesn't I found that on the computer where the code doesn't work I
>   have a directory Cookies under my user account and I see the file with
>   the cookies which I can't erase.
>
> On another machine where the code works I don't have a directory
>   Cookies under the user logged in even though I do see the file under
>   Temporary Internet Files directory.